# Razor syntax in helper containing HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, kendo-ui

I'm using the Kendo tabstrip helper and am attempting to describe the contents in HTML rather than pointing to a separate vbHTML file:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip() _
.Name("tab2") _
.Items(Function(tabstrip) tabstrip.Add().Text("Project") _
.Selected(True) _
.Content(Sub() @(<div>
                     <table id="SummaryDimPanel" class="table slim">
                           ...table contents...
                     </table>
               </div>)
         End Sub)))
```

(using the syntax suggested [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/issue-while-using-with-vbhtml)).

However this produces the error:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'content' can be
>   called with these arguments.

I'm sure this is just due to a gap in my Razor knowledge but am struggling to see the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a dialogue with Telerik support the answer became evident.  The `@()` syntax I was using doesn't work in vb.net and instead `@Code....End Code` should be used combined with a `sub() @<text> .... </text> End Sub` to encapsulate the HTML:

```
@code
    Html.Kendo().TabStrip() _
    .Name("tab2") _
    .Items(Function(tabstrip) tabstrip.Add().Text("Project") _
    .Selected(True).Content(Sub()@<text>
        <table id="SummaryDimPanel" class="table slim">
              ....table contents...
        </table>
    </text> End Sub)).Render()
End code
```

(This particular Kendo helper requires the addition of the .Render method to actually push the HTML to the browser).

And Voila!

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for C# but the kendo controls are the same:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("MoveItem")
.Title("Move Item")
.Visible(false)
.Modal(true)
.Draggable(false)
.Width(900)
.Content(@<text>
   <div>
     <div class="box-head">
           <h2>Select container where item should be moved to</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="box-content" style="font-size: 8pt">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Container>()
          .Name("CGrid_MoveItem")                                      
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(c => c.Barcode).Width(100);
              columns.Bound(c => c.NumberofItems).Title("Count").Width(70);
          })          
          .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))                  
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(a => a.Id);
                    model.Field(a => a.Barcode);    
                })                
              .Read(read => read.Action("Move_Read", "CoAdmin"))
            )
        )
        </div>
    </div>
</text>)
)
```

Comment: Many thanks for that but I'm afraid I don't think that helps me.  My understanding is that using the sub() @<text> or sub() @<div> is the vb.net syntax for what you've illustrated, but that is what I've done to produce the exception...